# How to get elements in complicated arrays from API themoviedb.org

Tags: php, arrays, api

I'm trying to write simple Telegram bot and use API of themoviedb.org for this purpose.

```
$url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=' . $weather_token;
$films = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), TRUE);
print_r($films);
```

I got such output (indeed there are much more elements but I stay just one, repeated elements removed:

```
Array(
    [page] => 1
    [results] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [id] => 581600
            [video] => 
            [vote_count] => 68
            [vote_average] => 6.9
            [title] => 
            Spenser Confidential[release_date] => 2020 - 03 - 06
            [original_language] => en
            [original_title] => Spenser Confidential
            [genre_ids] => Array(
                [0] => 28
                [1] => 35
                [2] => 53
                )
            [backdrop_path] => /ftODZXaXpWtV5XFD8gS9n9KwLDr.jpg 
            [adult] => 
            [overview] => Spenser, a former Boston patrolman who just got out from prison, teams up with Hawk, an aspiring fighter, to unravel the truth behind the death of two police officers. 
            [poster_path] => /uWHQRfso4sJp5aSLHabpWtJbbFb.jpg
            [popularity] => 92.018
            [media_type] => movie
            )
        )   
[total_pages] => 1000
[total_results] => 20000
)
```

I want to get title and overview, poster_path, but I failed.

I tried print_r($films['page']); but it show just 1.

When I tried print_r($films['page'][0]); it did nothing

I will hight appreciate Your help.

Comment: Welcome. I'd advise to read up on some [array basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 0):

My ex give me an answer:

```
foreach ($films['results'] as $film) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($film['title'], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```